# Setting up CUDA with docker meets the permission not granted problem

Tags: docker

I would like to setup cuda using the following code:

`docker run -ti --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 nvidia/cuda`

I Kept getting these Errors:

```
Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install docker     # version 18.06.1-ce, or
apt  install docker.io  # version 18.09.7-0ubuntu1~19.04.5

See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.
```

I tried to google these Errors, but failed.

System Environment: Ubuntu Desktop `19.04`
I should explain that this is a clean System I'm currently using.

Comment: please add the error message to the body of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should tell you one thing that, installing anything with docker comes with a prerequisite, which is that you should install docker first.

You can find the tutorials on how you could install docker in the following link:
[How to install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/install/)

And then you could install Nvidia compiled docker container with the following command:

```
docker pull nvidia/cuda
docker run -ti --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 nvidia/cuda
```

which was referenced from [Nvidia CUDA Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/) and [Nvidia CUDA GitHub page](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA)